# Rails query for joining tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables. Game and game_report

game table has fields : id, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_club_id, away_club_id etc

game_report has fields: id, game_id, report_type, team_id etc

team_id in game_report table is either home_team_id or away_team_id from game table.

I need a query to check in which if home_team_id and away_team_id from game table has the same report_type or not

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually use an instance method for this.

```
# app/models/game_report.rb
def is_home_team?
  self.team_id == self.game.home_team_id
end
```

That will return `true` if the report has the same team id as the game's home team id, and `false` if not.